# Axios not working on Mac - Safari / chrome in Vue mounted

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have been searching a lot , i still don't know what am i doing wrong , my boss went angry today to buy a mac to fig this out, iam on windows.

On windows, For chrome and moz, its working perfectly , but fails the request on safari & chrome.

**What my request is trying**

-fetch the cookies id  and collect info about the id from Database and return to my app.

**My code**

```js
mounted(){
  axios.get('/config/test.php/'+'?nocache='+ new Date().getTime({withCredentials:true})
  .then(resp => this.productsdb = resp.data)
  .then( resp=> {
    this.totiq = this.productsdb.length;
    console.log(resp)
  })             
},
```

**What have i tried :**

1. Added withCredentials:true  .
2. '?nocache='+ new Date().getTime() -> got this sol from stackoverflow .
3. also tried with fetch() api , no luck

**Php side:**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('cache-control: no-cache');
```

Comment: [Your description of the problem isn't very helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What *exactly* is failing? Use the developer tools in the browser, look at the Console for error messages and the Network tab to see what is being sent and received.

Comment: hello quentin, i don't have acces to mac now , to check the logs , i used https://app.lambdatest.com/console/realtime  a cross browser testing  site, its showing no error on catch mathod to , also no console.log(response) wierd.

Comment: If you're using `withCredentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` it suggests you're using CORS. Safari has much tighter restrictions on using cookies with CORS, you can only really use them for sites that share the same main domain. Here's something I wrote previously on the topic: https://cors-errors.info/faq#cdc8.